# Change frame of Live View in Swift playgrounds

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I can't figure out how to change the size of the `Live View frame` in Swift playgrounds. Here is my code:

```
public struct PlaygroundRootView: View {
    public var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .frame(width: 200, height: 100, alignment: .center)
            .foregroundColor(Color.blue.opacity(0.7))
            .cornerRadius(20)
     } 
} 
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = UIHostingController(rootView: PlaygroundRootView())
```

I want to make the `Live View` wider, changing its size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the `preferredContentSize` of the `UIHostingController`, as in:

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import SwiftUI

public struct PlaygroundRootView: View {
    public var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .frame(width: 200, height: 100, alignment: .center)
            .foregroundColor(Color.blue.opacity(0.7))
            .cornerRadius(20)
     }
}

let host = UIHostingController(rootView: PlaygroundRootView())
host.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 600, height: 600)
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = host
```

> Result

[image]

Comment: I don’t need to make the rectangle wider I need the view behind it. The white view controller or live view.

Comment: Oh, I see. You need `preferredContentSize` then. I edited my answer, please take a look.

Comment: i have tried it but still not working for xcode 12.4, somehow the frame wont change :/